# Can I identify squares using connectedComponents or findContours is better? Using opencv on Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on my first opencv and python project but I'm stuck.
The thing is, I need to identify the four squares in the corners, and then rotate the image, so they get aligned.

[(Image DG.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4PpX.jpg)

At first I tried using findContours, but when I try drawing the contours, it seems not to work. Here's the code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# ler a imagem
im = cv.imread('DQ.jpg', 0)
rett, im_bi = cv.threshold(im, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# definir dimensões da imagem
tam = np.shape(im)
print(tam)
A = round(tam[0] * 0.3)
L = round(tam[1] * 0.3)

# canny edges
edge = cv.Canny(im_bi, 30, 200)
cv.namedWindow('Canny edges', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow('Canny edges', edge)
cv.resizeWindow('Canny edges', L, A)
cv.waitKey(0)

contours, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(edge, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # how to fix??
cv.namedWindow('findContours', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow('findContours', edge)
cv.resizeWindow('findContours', L, A)
cv.waitKey(0)

cv.drawContours(im_bi, contours, -1, (0,255,39), 3)

cv.namedWindow('drawContours', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow('drawContours', im_bi)
cv.resizeWindow('drawContours', L, A)
cv.waitKey(0)

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then I thought of finding it's connected components, but after I find then I can't identify the squares. The second code, very similar to the first one:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# abre imagem e limiariza            0 = passar pra b&w
im = cv.imread('DQ.jpg', 0)
rett, im_bi = cv.threshold(im, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# calcula tamanhos da imagem
tam = np.shape(im)
A = round(tam[0] * 0.2)
L = round(tam[1] * 0.2)

# calcula negativo da imagem
neg = cv.bitwise_not(im_bi)

# mostra imagem negativa
cv.namedWindow("negativa", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL) # permite que alteremos o tamanho da janela
cv.imshow('negativa', neg)
cv.resizeWindow('negativa', L, A) # altera o tamanho da janela
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

# encontra os componentes conexos da imagem
connectivity = 8
ret, labels = cv.connectedComponents(neg, connectivity, cv.CV_32S)

# normaliza os rótulos para tons de cinza
label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))

cv.namedWindow("labeled", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow('labeled', label_hue)
cv.resizeWindow('labeled', L, A)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

# colors the labeled image, just for show
# blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
# rot_im = cv.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])
# rot_im = cv.cvtColor(rot_im, cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
# rot_im[label_hue == 0] = 0

# cv.namedWindow("final", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# cv.imshow('final', rot_im)
# cv.resizeWindow('final', L, A)
# cv.waitKey(0)
# cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The comments are in Portuguese, but it's not complicated as you can see, I just like to show all the images after I do something to them haha. I would like to know which one of the above would be better for my project. I myself would rather use connectedComponents because I understand better what it does to the image, but all similar tutorials I found use findContours.
Besides that, what should I do after? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/pCq3KnEy) might get you started. Don't think you need the canny, just threshold it low enough to pick the darker grays, get all contours, simplify them, find the quadrilaterals, remove anything not almost square and too big or too small.